# Change remote remote css locally

Tags: css, dns, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am currently accessing a website with a server which is running headless chrome and record the screen

Is there a possibility to change css on this machine locally?

My first thought was to play with dns to load a changed css file locally

Or use a proxy which rewrites one css file to a local one.

Any better/simpler solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change CSS locally
better use proxy